# How to utilize touch in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, touchscreen

Ok, so apparently Ubuntu is going in the direction of increasingly supporting touch and I'm perfectly fine with that. I just got the new laptop with touch screen and my question is - how can I utilize touch in the 16.04 version of Ubuntu?

For example: Small windows icons doesn't seem too touch friendly, how to deal with them? Is there anything that should be known by the touch beginners for everyday work?